# Get unique property pairs from object array (Angular 2+)

Tags: arrays, angular, object, unique

I'm trying to get an array of unique First Name + Last Name combinations from an object array in Angular 7.

Below is example data:

```
[{"First_Name": "Jane", "Last_Name": "Doe", "State": "Louisiana"},
{"First_Name": "John", "Last_Name": "Doe", "State": "Louisiana"},
{"First_Name": "Sally", "Last_Name": "Smith", "State": "Iowa"},
{"First_Name": "Sally", "Last_Name": "Smith", "State": "Pennsylvania"},
{"First_Name": "Jack", "Last_Name": "Welch", "State": "New York"}]
```

Ideally, it would return this (removes "State" and dedupes "Sally Smith"):

```
[{"First_Name": "Jane", "Last_Name": "Doe"},
{"First_Name": "John", "Last_Name": "Doe"},
{"First_Name": "Sally", "Last_Name": "Smith"},
{"First_Name": "Jack", "Last_Name": "Welch"}]
```

Below is my code.  It returns unique last names, but does not retrieve the first name.

```
getUniqueNames(list) {
    const valuelist = list.map(list => list['First_Name'] && list['Last_Name']);
    this.uniquevalues = valuelist.filter((x, i, a) => x && a.indexOf(x) === i);
    this.uniquevalues.sort(function(a, b){
        if(a < b) { return -1; }
        if(a > b) { return 1; }
        return 0;
    });
    return this.uniquevalues;
  }
```

How would be best to get the unique first name + last name list?

Comment: `list.map(list => list['First_Name'] && list['Last_Name'])` changes to `list.map(list => list['First_Name'] + list['Last_Name'])`?

Comment: Thanks, that concatenates the two values like {"JaneDoe"},{"JohnDoe"}.  I'm looking to get the values in smaller object array like {"First_Name": "Jane", "Last_Name": "Doe"},{"First_Name": "John", "Last_Name": "Doe"}

Comment: you just need to add some separator like comma when you concat first/last name and then split them for each element in uniquevalues

Comment: Thanks.  That helped get to the answer